# Using multiple Maven mirrors to pull different jar version into a project

Tags: maven

I am experiencing issues pulling in a new version of a library which lives in a different repository.  I believe I have to update my `settings.xml` and my parent level `pom.xml` which specifies the new version.

Currently my `settings.xml` reads like the following:

```
<settings>
   <mirrors>
      <mirror>
         <id>nexus</id>
         <url>http://serenity.gm.edu/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
         <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
      <mirror>
         <id>mods</id>
         <url>http://7.169.72.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
         <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
     <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <repositories>
           <repository>
              <id>mod-thirdparty</id>
              <url>http://7.169.72.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thridparty/</url>
           </repository>
           <repository>
              <id>mod-snapshots</id>
              <url>http://7.169.72.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
           </repository>
       </repositories>
   </profile>
</profiles>

<servers>
   <server>
      <id>Tomcat</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
   </server>
</servers>
```

The default mirror where everything gets pulled in from is **serenity**.  I am trying to pull in a custom library `mod3.2` from 7.169.72.8 but version 2.3 keeps getting pulled in from serenity.  I have tried a number of `<mirrorOf>` settings such as `*,!central` with no success.

My parent `pom.xml` is fairly straightforward defining a list of modules, proerties, and global dependencies.  Here are the items of interest (it is too long to show).

```
<project ...>
...
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <name>mod2-releases</name>
         <url>http://7.169.72.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
   </repository>
   <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>mod2-snapshots</name>
         <url>http://7.169.72.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
   </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<properties>
    ...
    <mod2.version>3.2</mod2.version>
    ...
</properties>

    ...

<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mod2.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>mod2.commons.lang</groupId>
         <version>${mod2.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mod2.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>mod2.commons.audit</groupId>
         <version>${mod2.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

To recap - I'm trying to get version mod2 version 3.2 from `7.169.72.8` but all I can pull in mod2 version 2.3 from the `serenity` repo.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maven has no reason to look for a version 2.3 here, since the version is explicitely 3.2. The profile `default` is not activated though, there should be a `<activeProfiles><activeProfile>default</activeProfile></activeProfiles>` in the settings. That said, even with this profile not activated, Maven should look into the serenity repo, fail, and then look into 7.169.72.8 (or the inverse, not sure if there's an order in the mirrors).

Comment: Exactly what I thought too.  Since the pom explicitly says 3.2, why is it pulling from `serenity` (i.e. 2.3)

Comment: Well somewhere, the version is being redefined. Your dependencies are inside a `dependencyManagement` so maybe a child project using those redefines the version to 2.3? Or there is a system property setting `mod2.version`?

Comment: The maven build does recognize that it needs 3.2 because it blows up saying `The following artifacts could not be resolved: mod2.commons:mod2.commons.audit:3.2 in nexus (http:serenity.gm.edu/nexus/content/groups/public/)`

Comment: Okay but now my other dependencies, maven-clean-plugin.jar, fail to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration, you are declaring multiple mirrors for the Central repository. However, [Maven does not support that](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html):

> Note that there can be at most one mirror for a given repository. In other words, you cannot map a single repository to a group of mirrors that all define the same  value. Maven will not aggregate the mirrors but simply picks the first match. If you want to provide a combined view of several repositories, use a repository manager instead.

In your case, Maven is picking the first mirror of Central, which is of id `nexus`, and ignoring the second one, which is of id `mods`. Therefore, when fetching for your artifact, it only searches `nexus` and fails to find it.

There are a couple of solutions:

- If you really want to have multiple mirrors for the same repository, you will need to use a [repository manager](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) and configure this on the repo manager itself.
- It's not clear why you need to mirror Central and point to `7.169.72.8:8081` if this repository doesn't have all the artifacts needed to make your build work. If the rest are hosted on `serenity.gm.edu`, you could host all of them on `serenity.gm.edu`.
- You could also not use the `mods` mirror at all. Let `serenity.gm.edu` be the mirror for Central and just declare a new repository that isn't Central to fetch your artifacts. You already declared the `mod-thirdparty` and `mod-snapshots` repositories, so this is a matter of activating the profile they are under with:

  ```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  ```

  in the `settings.xml`. With this, Maven will also look for your artifacts at the URL configured for those repo (and those are not mirrored by `nexus`).

Comment: I have no control over the repos, I have screamed at those who do, so I would have to go with option 3.  This would mean removing 7.169.72.8 as a mirror as a repo in `settings.xml` and adding the `activeProfile`?

Comment: @jnbbender Correct.

Comment: I added the `activeProfile` but no success.  I finally was able to get it working when I added it as a mirror again after the `serenity` entry specified as `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`.  So I now have 2 mirrors and an `activeProfile` of default.

Comment: @jnbbender But is that what you want? `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` will mirror _all_ repositories, not just Central, so all traffic will be redirected to `serenity.gm.edu`. Using option 3, Maven will look for the artifact at `http://7.169.72.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thridparty/mod2/commons/mod2.commons.audit/3.2`. What was the error you had? Can you see the `default` profile when running `mvn help:active-profiles`?

Comment: Yes I can see the default profile but it pulls only from `serenity` now.

Comment: @jnbbender I tested with your configuration (additionally removing the `mods` mirror and activating the `default` profile) and I can see requests to `7.169.72.8:8081` being made. Make sure the `nexus` mirror only mirrors Central with `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>`. Check `mvn help:effective-settings` to make sure everything is correct.